# Shared Windows folder only contains the first ~15 subfolders

Tags: windows, 15.10, samba, windows-10, shared-folders

I've got a Windows 10 system with two shared folders: *FolderC* and *FolderE*.
*FolderC* resides on my primary hard drive, *FolderE* on my secondary.

From a Ubuntu 15.10 system I want to access these two directories.

- *FolderC* shows only the first 10 or sometimes 15 or 20 entries. At some point the alphabetically sorted list of subfolders is cut off.
- *FolderE* lists all subfolders without a problem.

The file permissions on Windows are identical for all folders. On the command line in Ubuntu I get the same list of folders shown as in the file manager.

Where could the problem be?

---

**P. S.**: On another Windows 10 machine I see all folders.

Comment: If you can see on the other Windows 10 machine all the folders then there could be a problem with samba version compatibility between Windows 10 and Ubuntu.

Comment: @kukulo Unfortunately the problem occurs with openSUSE Tumbleweed as well. :-(

Comment: Please check the samba version for win10. Ubuntu 15.10 comes with samba 4 i think. The opensuse will be not an exception. The question will be whether win 10 supports lower version of samba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 10 will try to negotiate SMB3_11, which Samba4 doesn't yet support except in the current 4.3 release candidate. I suspect for now disabling SMB2/3 on the Windows 10 client is your best, if not ideal, option.

Instructions for doing this can be found here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2696547

The answer is from here: http://www.tenforums.com/network-sharing/31136-samba-shares-dont-show-up-windows-10-network.html

Comment: openSUSE Tumbleweed uses the Samba version 4.3.5. Isn't this version already newer than 4.3 RC?
And if there was a problem with Windows 10 in general shouldn't that affect both folders?

Comment: Hard to say, because only MS can see the source of windows code. Usually when debugging such errors you need to have access to both sources.

Comment: Your problem description leads me to the conclusion that MS did something very different in their Win 10 Samba implementation.